Is workflow transition history mandatory for workflow to work normally?
I am trying to export content using content sync and im facing issue with workflow_transition entity .However i'm able to export nodes with states without any issue . Content sync doesnt support exporting entities that doesnt have uuid . workflow_transition entity doesnt have uuid and i found that this entity is used only for storing logs of nodes when moved from one state to another . So i'm thinking of skipping this entity . Is that safe to do, or will it break something?
